# Entity Framework - Insert a many-to-many relationship from a FormView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, objectdatasource, formview

I have two entities linked with an association entity. In code I can easily insert  one, or all of these at once. But, on the front end, I am using FormViews to allow the user to enter data. When I insert an address, how do I let it know to insert a facility at the same time, unless I have the facility and the address on the same formview?

```
Public Class facility

  <Key()> _
  Public Property facility_id As Integer
  Public Property facility_present_use As String
  Public Property facility_prior_use As String
  Public Property facility_occupied As Boolean
  Public Property facility_size As Double
  Public Property facility_floors As Integer
  Public Property facility_age As Integer
  Public Property facility_single_residence As Boolean
  Public Property facility_number_of_units As Integer      

  Public Overridable Property facility_address As ICollection(Of facility_address) = New HashSet(Of facility_address)

End Class

Public Class address

  <Key()> _
  Public Property address_id As Integer
  Public Property address_name As String
  Public Property address_address_1 As String
  Public Property address_address_2 As String
  Public Property address_city As String
  Public Property address_state As Integer?
  Public Property address_zip As String
  Public Property address_contact_first_name As String
  Public Property address_contact_last_name As String
  Public Property address_phone_area As String
  Public Property address_phone As String

  Public Overridable Property lu_state As lu_state
  Public Overridable Property facility_address As ICollection(Of facility_address) = New HashSet(Of facility_address)

End Class

Public Class facility_address

  <Key()> _
  Public Property facility_address_id As Integer
  Public Property address_type As Integer
  Public Property facility_id As Integer
  Public Property address_id As Integer

  Public Overridable Property lu_address_type As lu_address_type
  Public Overridable Property facility As facility
  Public Overridable Property address As address
End Class
```